# How to handle Parse.com's PFTableView image before it is displayed

Tags: ios, uiimage, parse-platform

This question is about the Parse.com ios (objective-c) framework.

Hi everyone!

I am using the Parse's PFTableView and i would like to dynamically blur the PFImageView inside the PFTableViewCell when it is fetched. It seems that the PFTableView is automatically handling all the process of fetching the images for us. I can't figure out if there's a callback or completion handler so I can process the blur effect on the PFImageView's image before it is displayed.

What would be the best way to achieve this?

Thank you ladies and gentlemen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In all likelihood, the right approach is to not use `PFImageView`... download the image contents yourself (or use another 3rd-party library to make it easier,) and customize the behavior from there.

The provided UI libraries, `PFImageView`, `PFLoginViewController`, `PFSignupViewController`, and `PFQueryTableViewController` are largely for handling the basic scenarios.